# Are proofreading requests on topic?

Tags: discussion

As an exercice to learn the language, I'd like to set myself the task of writing a few dozen words of Russian a day. Like short diary entries, or something. Is it acceptable to post a short text, say 50-100 words, and ask if there are any mistakes? I'm particularly worried that I'd flood the board if I posted such questions regularly, say at a rate of one a week.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid they're not on topic.

However you can ask specific questions for whatever you have doubts on. Say there is a particular grammar structure/rule you're having trouble with, you can ask about that.

Make sure that the question hasn't been already asked.